# Vue-FontAwesome: How to import all Free and Pro Icons? Duplicate declaration error

Tags: vue.js, import, font-awesome

I own a FontAwesome Pro License and I use the Vue-FontAwesome Component.

When I try to import all icons from both the free and Pro repo I get an "Duplicate declaration error ..." and if I change the declaration name it can't be found anymore.

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import { fal } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'

library.add(fab)
library.add(fas)
library.add(far)
library.add(fal)
```

How do I import all icons from Free and Pro?

Comment: Aren't all the icons in Free also included in Pro? Everything I've ever bought where I upgraded from free to pro included everything in free plus a bunch of additional stuff added by pro. Why do you need both?

Comment: thanks! I found out that my issue was something else: with the way I displayed them <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'heart']" /> rather than <font-awesome-icon :icon="heart" />

Answer (score 3):

I tried to add Fontawesome pro icons to Vuetify(1.5.x). I found a solition. I share this solution with you.

First of all, in your project directory, create a file called *.npmrc* and add this to it:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX,
```

install fontawesome-pro package with npm or yarn

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro
```

or

```
yarn add --dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro
```

Add this line in app.js or main.js

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css'
```

Install pro icon packages

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons
```

You can use with pro icons with prefix (*fas* solid, *far* regular *fal* light. That's all you can use pro icons. I hope work with your project. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

You're in effect importing multiple icon packs into to the same var for both `far` and `fas`, hence the error "Duplicate declaration".

As stated in comments, if you have **FontAwesome Pro**, that includes everything in FontAwesome Free. Import the pro-packages you need, and forget about the free edition.

That being said, importing the entire thing isn't ideal. If you're using a bundle manager with tree shaking (i.e webpack), it will save your application's weight impact tenfold. You rarely need all of the 5k icons.

Continuing down that road, that is; not importing the entire package: You can import different icon versions by importing and casting them. Like so:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

import { faCoffee as fasCoffee } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { faCoffee as farCoffee } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons'
import { faCoffee as falCoffee } from '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons'

library.add(fasCoffee, farCoffee, falCoffee)
```

More on all of this in [the official docs for FA-Pro](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome#add-more-styles-or-pro-icons).